# ssh problem caused by create another github account and add an new ssh

Tags: github, ssh

I created a new github account, and therefore I need a new ssh key, but after set ssh key properly, i cannot push my project.
After created a new ssh key, I added a config file in .ssh directory as following:

```
# one(one@gmail.com)

Host eric

HostName github.com

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

User eric



# two(two@ gmail.com)

Host nuist

HostName github.com

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_id

User nuist
```

and I run: ssh -T -v nuist, received following instructioins:

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Leonard/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/Leonard/.ssh/config line 15: Applying options for nuist
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Leonard/.ssh/github_id type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Leonard/.ssh/github_id-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-0913e7e1
debug1: no match: babeld-0913e7e1
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'nuist'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Leonard/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/Leonard/.ssh/github_id RSA SHA256:6phvZZlW2357l+xFxmE4xSuMr1EsOFm/owFL2gikjSU explicit agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/Leonard/.ssh/github_id RSA SHA256:6phvZZlW2357l+xFxmE4xSuMr1EsOFm/owFL2gikjSU explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
nuist@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
```

However, after run I: ssh -T git@github.com, it turned out successfully.

I am guessing that the config file didn't work, but cannot be sure.

I can't see where the problem is, and i had set the ssh in my github account likewise.

Can anyone give a hand? I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new key for a new account, just add your other id as collaborator with full access.

Your config for access to github should use `User git` for both hosts if testing that way.

Run `ssh-add -l` to check that keys have been loaded.

Run `git remote -v` to check the github fetch/push urls and see if those match the ssh link provided by github.

If they don't match, you can set with `git remote set-url origin <github-ssh-url>` *replace  with the link github says.*

Comment: But if I use my current public key to a new account, github warned that key is already in use, and cannot add.

And I run `git remote -v` and get the correct ssh url, but after run git push, it warns that: Permission to NUIST-elite/question-bank.git denied to Funguy-Eric.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

NUIST-elite is my account and Funguy_Eric is my old account.